# Gallery not displaying images when clicking on them

Tags: custom-post-types, gallery

I've inserted a wordpress gallery in to my site (on a custom post type) using the editor. The code it's added is `[gallery link="file"]`. The gallery is displaying correctly, and when hovering over the images, I can see the correct URL for the large size image: "http://localhost:8888/mntn/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P1000857.jpg".

However, when I click on the image, the larger image doesn't display. Alls that happens is that the url changes from:

```
http://localhost:8888/mntn/trips/photo-gallery-test
```

to

```
http://localhost:8888/mntn/trips/photo-gallery-test#!prettyPhoto[pp_gal]/0/
```

The last number in that URL is incremented based on the image I click on. Any ideas as to what's wrong here?

Comment: Is the gallery supposed to show full image as thickbox does or you want to link to file directly.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I think those extra parameters in url (after-`#`) are generated to make that plugin work with browser history. I think the plugin doesn't loading required javascript to popup full sized images. thats why it only updating url but not showing full sized image.

See the source code of page to make sure you're loading all necessary JavaScript files.

NOTE - Some plugin uses javascript to show full image on same page (without refreshing it). So when you browse through different images the url remains same and if you want to view last viewed image the browser back button won't work.

To make sure the browser back button work, the javascript add those extra parameters in url each time you open new image in gallery.

Comment: Hi Amit. I'm not using a plugin. This is the standard Wordpress plugin I'm talking about.

Comment: From the links given in your question, It seems you are using - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/prettyphoto-media/ plugin 

make sure you're not installed it..